# How to work with non-traditional UART baud rates

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, uart, baud-rate

I am trying, unsuccessfully to communicate, using my Arduino Nano, with a custom device at a baud rate of 800 kbit/s.

The Arduino code look like this:

```
void setup() {
  // Put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(800000);
}

void loop() {
  // Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println(0x2be1);
}
```

When I am trying to debug it with PuTTY the result is:

[image: PuTTY output @ 800 kb/s]

And when I change the baud rate to 400 kbit/s the result is (as it should be):

[image: PuTTY output @ 400 kb/s]

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Arduino Nano cannot do 800 kb/s. As you can see in [the source
code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L106), the bit duration is rounded to the nearest multiple of
8 CPU cycles. In your case, it is rounded to
3 × 8 CPU cycles, which yields a baud rate of
666.666 kb/s. That is 16% too slow, an error too large for any
communication to be possible.

At 400 kb/s there is no rounding error, so everything works fine.

**Edit**: Note that if you build your own [barebones
Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone), then either a 12.8 MHz or a 19.2 MHz
crystal should allow you to get that exact baud rate. But then
`millis()`, `delay()` and co. would all be off.